# mono audio in audioSprite / ffmpeg has the same bitrate as stereo

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg

I'm using [audioSprite](https://github.com/tonistiigi/audiosprite) that uses ffmpeg for encoding. I need to make mono files in order to reduce (halve) file sizes.

As an audio professional, I thought this was a simple job. Downmix, encode the mono output, done. It turns out nothing happens to the file sizes. The aac, ogg, m4a and mp3 mono output files from audioSprite are identical in size to the stereo files.

First time I ran audioSprite with stereo source files and the switch `-c 1`.  So perhaps ffmpeg considers the source. Ran the same thing with a mono source file. Again, identical file size.

Anybody knows what's going on or what I would need to do?

Comment: Have you checked the result files regarding a bitrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool sets a [fixed default target bitrate](https://github.com/tonistiigi/audiosprite/blob/master/audiosprite.js#L241). No matter how many channels, you're going to get that bitrate.

Change the target bitrate accordingly (i.e., half of the default when using mono).

Comment: Thank you very much slhck!

A bit embarrassing. It makes sense that 128kb/sec should stay 128kb/sec, regardless of channel count. It is just NOT the way linear formats work. :o)